# Understanding how the Tensorflow Model class turns Layers/Tensors into Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

the `outputs` is a Tensor object. When we make the `model` object we encapsulate the `input`, `x`, and `outputs` object into one `tf.Model` object. My confusion comes from how the model is able to do this. Isn't there not enough information in order to encapsulate the full thing? When I check the `model.layers` property it returns all three layers, and not two. It is clear that we only gave two inputs (`inputs` and `outputs`) to the constructor of the `tf.keras.Model` class so how is it able to access the intermediate layer `x` given these parameters?

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is able to reason that to get to outputs you have to go through layer x. It especially needs this capability to do backpropagation and update all weights.

Comment: How would tensorflow be able to "reason," though?